# Does Intellij IDEa Ultimate have support for Node.js deployments in App Engine?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, gcloud

Do I miss something or there is no support for deployment of Node.js apps in Gcloud App Engine?
I found a separate plugin for php, full support for java in the plugin Google Cloud Tools but nothing on Node.js.

In java you just check a box and you got app.yaml automatically build, uploading and running and debugging tools, integration with API, everything you need.

I can't find how to enable this tools for a standard Express app so I hope I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Google Cloud Tools for IntelliJ does not currently support non-Java based App Engine runtimes. We may add support eventually but we have no concrete plans to do so at the moment.

Comment: Got it Patrick, thanks for the update.
Let me know if you want a feedback on what to improve for new comers like me. :)

Comment: hi @SharpBCD. we always love getting feedback. Feel free to follow up on our GitHub issue tracker any time: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/new